# How to get data based on condition from nested array golang grpc service

Tags: arrays, go, nested, grpc, nested-attributes

I'm trying to get specific data based on next array condition in Go. I think, I will just give an example to make it clear.

Let's say I have an array like this

```
detail: {

   contacts: [

      {

         email: "testing@gmail.com"

         condition: {
               
              valid: "Yes",

              verified: "No"

         }

      },

      {

         email: "testing2@gmail.com"

         condition: {

              valid: "Yes",

              verified: "Yes"

         }

      }

   ]

}
```

So, I'm trying to get the email as a return after calling grpc function if the condition has verified "Yes" on it.

```
result, err := grpcService.callingService.GetContactDetail(ctx, &contactServicePb.GetContactDetailRequest{
    ContactId: "123",
})
if err != nil {
    return err
}
```

This is what I tried so far, I can access the contacts list but I don't know how do I take email which belong to "Yes" verified.

fmt.Println(result.Detail.Contacts)

this is how the output looks like

```
      {

         email: "testing@gmail.com"

         condition: {

              valid: "Yes",

              verified: "No"

         }

      },

      {

         email: "testing2@gmail.com"

         condition: {

              valid: "Yes",

              verified: "Yes"

         }

      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over `result.Detail.Contacts` array and store contacts' email with "Yes" verified condition:

```golang
verifiedEmails := []string{}

for _, contact := range result.Detail.Contacts {
    if contact.condition.verified == "Yes" {
        validEmails = append(validEmails, contact.email)
    }
}

fmt.Println(validEmails)
```